# How to store function output into an array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, signal-processing

```
w=logspace(-2,2,100);
H1={}
a=[1 (2/sqrt(2)) 1];
b=[0 0 1];
freqs(b,a,w)
loglog(w,abs(H1)^20,'ro',10,10);
```

I want to store the output to freq(b,a,w) into the array H1. How do I do this so that I can then generate a plot for H1?

Comment: remove `H1={}`. Instead, do `H1=freqs(b,a,w)`, and in the plot function change `^` to `.^`.

Comment: What @jrook said: `H1 = freqs(b,a,w);`, but there’s probably a mistake in `abs(H1)^20`: you never want to raise something to the 20th power, you probably want to plot in decibels (dB)? Then, that’s `loglog(w, 20 * log10(abs(H1)), 'ro')`.